# How to stop a background thread when an image window is closed in dm-script

Tags: dm-script

I'm trying to write a dm-script containing a background thread as following example code. In this code, I want to stop the background thread when the image window is closed. I think that some event-listener is probably required in this case. Could you advise me about how to control (i.e., stop) a background thread by closing event of an image window? If you could suggest some revision of my code or show your example code, I would be grateful for your cooperation.

```
// $BACKGROUND$
//
Class CBackground : Thread
{
    Number isRunning
    Number imgID
    Image tmpIMG
//
    Void Init( Object self, Number iID ){
        imgID = iID
        tmpIMG := GetImageFromID( imgID ) 
    }
//
    Void StopRunning( Object self ){
        isRunning = 0
    }
//
    Number GetIsRunning( Object self ){
        return isRunning
    }
//
    Void RunThread( Object self ){
        Result("Background thread is starting ......")
        isRunning = 1
        while (isRunning)
        {
            tmpIMG = random()
            sleep(0.5)
        }
        Result(" finished !!" + "\n")
    }
}
//
Void Main(){
    Object cbkg = alloc(CBackground)
    Image IMG := RealImage("test",4,64,64)
    IMG = random()
    IMG.ShowImage()
    IMG.SetWindowSize(512,512)
    cbkg.Init(IMG.GetImageID())
    cbkg.StartThread()
}
//
Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is an example of a script which uses a *window-closed* listener to abort the task.

```
Class CBackgroundWithListeners 
{
    Number isRunning
    Number imgID
    Image tmpIMG
    Number winListenID


    // Constructor and Destructor method for debugging reason
    // Always automatically called when object gets created or removed from memory
    CBackgroundWithListeners(object self) { 
        Result( "\n Creating object " + self.ScriptObjectGetClassName() )
        Result( " with ID: " + self.ScriptObjectGetID() )
    }
    ~CBackgroundWithListeners(object self) { 
        Result( "\n Destroying object " + self.ScriptObjectGetClassName() )
        Result( " with ID: " + self.ScriptObjectGetID() )
    }

    // Init Method
    Void Init( Object self, Number iID ){
        imgID = iID
        tmpIMG := GetImageFromID( imgID ) 
        If ( !tmpIMG.ImageIsValid() )
            Throw( "Image of ID " + imgID + " not found." )
        if ( 0 == tmpIMG.ImageCountImageDisplays() )
            Throw( "Image of ID " + imgID + " has no display." )

        DocumentWindow win = tmpIMG.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetWindow()
        if ( !win.WindowIsValid() )
            Throw( "Image of ID " + imgID + " has no window." )

        winListenID = win.WindowAddWindowListener( self, "window_closed:HandleClosedAction;" ) 
    }
//
    Void StopRunning( Object self ){
        isRunning = 0
    }
//
    Number GetIsRunning( Object self ){
        return isRunning
    }
//    
    Void HandleClosedAction(object self, number e_fl, DocumentWindow Win)
    {
        self.StopRunning()
        win.WindowRemoveWindowListener( winListenID )
    }
//
    Void RunThread( Object self ){
        Result("Background thread is starting ......")
        isRunning = 1
        while (isRunning)
        {
            tmpIMG = random()
            sleep(0.5)
        }
        Result(" finished !!" + "\n")
    }
}
//
Void Main(){
    Object cbkg = alloc(CBackgroundWithListeners)
    Image IMG := RealImage("test",4,64,64)
    IMG = random()
    IMG.ShowImage()
    IMG.SetWindowSize(512,512)
    cbkg.Init(IMG.GetImageID())
    cbkg.StartThread()
}
//
Main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful advices and showing of your helpful examples of dm-script. Stopping method of a background thread by using a window-closed listener is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a lot for your nice answers again!

Answer (score 1):

You can not stop a background thread from outside that thread, i.e. you can not *interrupt* a thread. In order to stop a background thread, the according code needs to have a stop-condition and exit itself.

In order to steer this stop-condition from another thread, you need to "communicate" somehow between two threads. This can be done in many different ways. The easiest is to use a simple number variable which is checked by the background running code but can be set via any other "outside" code. [An example for this can be found in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984182/1302888).

Instead of a simple variable, one could also use some commonly accessible place like f.e. the *global tags*. Alternatively, some more sophistacted threading synchronisation objects like *signals*, *mutexes* and *semphores* are defined for the scripting language and describe in the help documentation here:
[image: Help on threading]

*How* an external thread inserts the 'break' into the background running thread can also be done in many different ways. One is - as in the exampe above - have a user interaction via some open dialog. Another, as mentioned by the author, is to have some event-listener code to trigger this. 
The following example attaches a key-listener to the image, so that (with this image frontmost and selected) a user can press the ESC button to stop the thread.

I am using the provided script with minimum modifications for showing this:

```
// $BACKGROUND$
//
Class CBackground : Thread
{
    Number isRunning
    Number imgID
    Number keyListenID
    Image tmpIMG
//
    Void Init( Object self, Number iID ){
        imgID = iID
        tmpIMG := GetImageFromID( imgID ) 
        ImageDisplay disp = tmpIMG.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
        keyListenID = disp.ImageDisplayAddKeyHandler( self, "KeyListenAction" )
    }
//
    Void StopRunning( Object self ){
        isRunning = 0
    }
//
    Number GetIsRunning( Object self ){
        return isRunning
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Number  KeyListenAction(Object self, ImageDisplay disp, Object keydesc ) 
    {
        number b_keyhandled = 0
        If ( keydesc.MatchesKeyDescriptor("esc") ) 
        {
            disp.ImageDisplayRemoveKeyHandler( keyListenID )
            self.StopRunning()
            Result( "\nSend stopping flag, unregister Key-Listeners" )
            b_keyhandled = 1
        }
        return b_keyhandled;
    }
//
    Void RunThread( Object self ){
        Result("Background thread is starting ......")
        isRunning = 1
        while (isRunning)
        {
            tmpIMG = random()
            sleep(0.5)
        }
        Result(" finished !!" + "\n")
    }
}
//
Void Main(){
    Object cbkg = alloc(CBackground)
    Image IMG := RealImage("test",4,64,64)
    IMG = random()
    IMG.ShowImage()
    IMG.SetWindowSize(512,512)
    cbkg.Init(IMG.GetImageID())
    cbkg.StartThread()
}
//
Main()
```

However, there are a few things I would do differently:

- Start the background thread with the proper command rather then the old '$$BACKGROUND$$' method.
- Encapsulate as much as possible into the class
- Add a few security checkes
- Also add a *windows closed* event listener, so that closing the image window also stops the thread
- Add some debug-code to show when an object is created and when it is removed from memory
- Have the keylistener to pause/unpause the action.